# 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' Error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

The code below is throwing an error at the beginning of the if statement. I believe it has something do with the character array, however I am not sure why that is. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 public void display_bits(int count)
    {

        //bits that will be displayed

        string[] disp_bits = new string[1000]; 
        string[] disp_to_bits = new string[1000];

        int disp_count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            char[] chars = { '~', '+', '*' };


            if (bits[i].IndexOfAny(chars) != 0)
            {

                bits[i] = disp_bits[disp_count];
                to_bits[i] = disp_to_bits[disp_count];
                disp_count++;

            }         
        }
    }
```

Comment: where exactly is the error?

Comment: if (bits[i].IndexOfAny(chars) != 0)

Comment: What is the value of `count`?

Comment: The value of `count` is 218

Comment: For future reference, you may wan tot think about the difference between a compiler error and a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

The `bits` string array doesn't appear to be initialized.

and

`for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)`

might need changing to

`for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`

So that your `i` index doesn't go outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: I did that in the class. Its a global variable

Comment: And it's definitely initialized i.e using the `new` keyword?

Comment: Yes, I initialized it in the begining of the class using the sytax below:   string[] bits = new string[1000]; 
        string[] to_bits = new string[1000];

Comment: All of which was done in the beginning of the class I created

Comment: It could be that `for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)` needs changing to `for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)`

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Jimmy, you initialized only 218 elements?

Comment: @Roma So I initialized 1000, because I am going to use this software to parse various text files. I made the bits and to_bits string arrays in the beginning of the class, and passed in 218 because that was the length of the string array after parsing.

Comment: because `i` starts at 0, and you're using a raw `count` (that starts at 1) to terminate the loop. So if there are 1000 items and you say _"continue this loop whilst `i` is less than or equal to `1000`"_ it will loop 1001 times and on the 1001st iteration you won't have a string to operate against because the array doesn't hold that many.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Most welcome. Don't forget to mark as answer if this was helpful. Thanks.